# Why I am getting 404 for this nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: regex, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I want to set up nginx as a reverse proxy and this is my current config

```
location /oracle/(.+) {
    proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
    proxy_set_header Access-Controll-Allow-Origin *;

    proxy_pass  https://www.oracle.com/$1;
    proxy_hide_header 'x-frame-options';
    proxy_hide_header 'access-controll-allow-origin';

}
```

But when I goto `localhost/oracle/index.html` I am getting a 404. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a valid `regex` with `~` as prefix for `location` block.

**Problems:**

> **1.** `Access-Controll-Allow-Origin` should be corrected to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with correct spelling.
>
> **2.** `\/oracle\/(.+)` Regex should be corrected to this.

**Note:**

> Regular expressions are specified with the preceding `~*` for `case-insensitive` and `~` for `case-sensitive`

**Change this to:**

`location /oracle/(.+) {`

**this:**

`location ~\/oracle\/(.+) {`

You can have a look at [nginx location reference](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Comment: It worked. So I am accepting this as the correct answer. But the proxy is not working. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @IsuruPathirana I have updated my post can you please check again.

Comment: Well $1 is to map that regex pattern into the remote URL. I am getting 502 error here. I think it will be better to post this as a separate question.